# jQuery Don't Delete Last Table Row

Tags: jquery

Please forgive me, I'm new to web programming. I just started with jQuery yesterday and I need a bit of help. I need to make sure that a user cannot delete the last row of a table. I am able to use the following successfully:

```
$(this).closest('tr:not(:only-child)').remove();
```

But I would like to display an alert message if the row is the last row instead of just not doing anything. I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
if( $(this).closest('tr:only-child') ) {
    alert('cannot delete last row');
}
else {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to not delete the bottom row of the column, or not allow the user to delete a row if it's the only row in the column? Those are going to be very different.

Comment: I am wanting to stop them from deleting the last remaining row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
if( $(this).closest('tr').is('tr:only-child') ) {
    alert('cannot delete last row');
}
else {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: That won't work because `.closest('tr')` will return a jQuery object with 1 element, and `:last` will check to see if the element is the last one in the set (which it always will be since there's only one). You want `tr:last-child` instead.

Comment: patrick is correct. But I was able to use the .is and come up with this that worked: `if( $(this).closest('tr').is('tr:only-child'))`

Answer (score 2):

To delete rows but allow *any* row to be the last (non-deletable) row:

```
$('td').click(
    function(){
        if ($(this).closest('table').find('tr').length > 1) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
        else {
            alert("Can't delete rows of class 'noDelete.'");
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZGHL2/).

To delete any rows *except* those of a 'noDelete' class-name:

```
$('td').click(
    function(){
        if (!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass('noDelete')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
        else {
            alert("Can't delete the last row.");
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZGHL2/2/).

Answer (score 0):

How about counting the number of `<tr>` elements in the table's `<tbody>` using this:

```
$(this).closest('tbody').children('tr').length
```